# Jacobi method on first order partial differential equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

Hi,

I am interested in the Jacobi method to solve partial differential equation of first order. I would like to have a hint about a good book to study this subject.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter VII of É. Goursat's book, [Leçons sur l'intégration des équations aux dérivées partielles du premier ordre](http://name.umdl.umich.edu/ACR1803.0001.001), exposes the method and ends with 14 examples of applying it (pp. 168-169).

Answer (score 2):

For starters see e.g. chapter IX of Forsyth's classical [Treatise on Differential Equations](http://books.google.com/books?id=hQgZ94-coocC).

Answer (score 2):

I think that Arnold's explanation in his book "Geometricam methods ..." is really great. Complement it with Courant-Hilbert and you'll understand all the basics.

Comment: Agreed! It's good to learn both the classical and modern (symplectic) views of this.